# openstreetmaps 0/0/0.png 404

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

I have followed the manual and package install on switch2osm.org as well as several others that are all similar.

I have loaded everything into the DB successfully. I used mapnik generate_xml & generate_image.py successfully producing the image.png map.

I ran 
**renderd -f -c /etc/renderd.conf**

which ended without errors with the return 
**renderd[27896]: Using web mercator projection settings**

I have tried navigating to /var/www/osm/0/0/0.png but it is 404, as well as osm_tiles and osm_tiles2 as I have seen in other install guides.

So, what part of the install actually configs the file path? 
Are there any other tests I can do to verify my installation?

Comment: `renderd` exited? This doesn't sound right. Check the logs and the return code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renderd only renders tiles, to serve them you need `mod_tile`, an Apache module. It is probably already installed, but you would need to enable mod_tile manually: see [this page](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/) for instructions (search by "Configure mod_tile").

Renderd and mod_tile do not produce actual image files in your directory tree, so to see `/0/0/0.png`, you'll have to open `http://localhost/<tile_URI>/0/0/0.png`, where `<tile_URI>` is defined in `/usr/local/etc/renderd.conf`.